# Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am deploying a django app for the first time to Heroku. I used the following:

heroku run python manage.py migrate

and it returns :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

In my settings.py i have :

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': dj_database_url.config(
        default=config('DATABASE_URL')
    )
}
```

and at the bottom :

```
try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

in the local_settings.py I have :

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'newapp_development',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '#####',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Do you know why is the error message  please ?
Also, note that local_settings is added to . gitignore.

I did a few search on search engine and the responses that i found did not work for me or were not clear enough to me. This is the reason why I took the risk of asking publicly here.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What happened when you tried putting, for example, `heroku could not connect to server` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=heroku+could+not+connect+to+server)? When I tried that, the linked duplicate was two clicks away.

Comment: Hi @KarlKnechtel, I did a few search on search engine and the responses that i found did not work for me or were not clear enough to me. This is the reason why I took the risk of asking publicly here.

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to check with your firewall inbound outbound rules, needs to add rules to accept this particular port.

or else please turn off the firewall and check again.